# How do the men get out?

Tags: riddle

Four men enter an empty room with

> 1. No doors,
> 2. no windows,
> 3. no entrances and
> 4. no exits.

The walls, floor, and ceiling are EXTRA THICC, so they cannot break their way out in any way.

How will the men get out?

P.S. They got out the same way they got in.

Comment: **THICC** lol +1

Comment: _I hope no-one can answer it..._ uh oh

Comment: It has extra thicc walls but does it have the same thiccness ceiling?

Comment: Yes IT Alex, the ceiling and floor are the same amount of EXTRA THICCness

Comment: The answer is: IDSPISPOPD

Comment: Uhm... What made you think that Ctx? And that isn't the answer... Sorry

Comment: @BenDover Then take that as a riddle for you ;)

Comment: Did you just "no u" me in riddle form?

Comment: Would a stairway be considered an entrance/exit?

Comment: Is the word `thicc` used deliberately? Were they ingested by some creature? Then they will leave "the natural way" some time later ;)

Comment: Ctx, it's internet language. Get used to it (xD)

Comment: I am used to it, that's why I asked if it was used _by purpose_ in this case.

Comment: Did they use the stairs to get in? Is it like an attic or something?

Comment: 40 ; wow, my gmail account got hacked twice already... I need more information security.

Comment: Look Moderators and 3000 rep or more ppl, I'm sorry I asked more than one question in this riddle, so I simplified it to one question.

(Please put my question off hold now ;-;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly

> The statement is ambiguous. In what appears to be a "locked room" riddle, we naturally parse the intro and bullets as

Image:

> [image: Diagram parsing the sentence with "Four men" as a noun phrase and the rest of the sentence as a verb phrase, where "a room with no doors" is a noun phrase and "with no doors" is a prepositional phrase applying to "a room".]

In other words,

> ***four men enter (a room which has no doors etc.)***. But we *could* parse it as

Image:

> [image: Sentence diagram parsing "four men" as a noun phrase, "enter a room" as a verb phrase, and "with no doors" as a prepositional phrase which applies to "four men".]

In other words,

> ***four men (who don't have doors etc. with them) enter an empty room.*** In this interpretation, the only things we know about the room itself are that it is empty and has reinforced walls and ceilings. But it could still have an ordinary complement of openings, which the men took advantage of to enter and can also use to exit. Note that this ambiguity could have been avoided by splitting the intro into two sentences: *Four men enter an empty room. The room has 1. No doors* and so forth.

Comment: I really want this to be the answer.   Nice thought process.

Comment: Wait, how did you find it out? I actually thought no-one could find out, since none of my friends and family could. Well done!

Comment: Probably the stack exchange I visit the most helps, @BenDover :). I really enjoyed your riddle, so thanks!

Comment: So did they starve to death shortly after?

Answer (score 13):

Maybe it's

> An internet chatroom. They entered by logging in, and they will leave by logging out.

Comment: Woah, I like that answer. But it isn't the answer...

Answer (score 8):

My guess:

> They were not born yet. That's why they can't build a tunnel or the walls are "extre thicc"

Comment: nnnnnnope. But wow, that was a hella good guess.

Comment: are they in the outer space? inside some kind of ship? they can't make they way out because they would die...

Comment: Sorry, not quite the answer...


**thinks in mind** *dang, I think I made it too difficult...*

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps

> It is a room made of ice, or a cave with an ice sheet blocking the entrance (raining and below freezing).

Then they

> Used heat to melt an entrance, but the rain fell and froze, sealing it back.  They could use their heat source again to open a new exit.

Comment: I like your answer as well, but it isn't quite correct. Great effort, though!

Comment: very nice! +1 Btw, welcome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe...

> One of the men is a priest, he'll bless the wall to make it holy, then they'll climb out the holes.

Answer (score 4):

> They slept and clearly need to wake up.

Comment: Hilarious, and Creative! Nice answer. Also, welcome to puzzling.se

Answer (score 4):

> The walls are not connected leaving a space to move in and out of the room

Answer (score 3):

> They were extremely lucky. The quantum mechanical tunneling effect *is* a real thing and gives the four men a small, but positive chance to enter and leave the room straight through the walls.
> Douglas Adam's improbability drive would help here of course.

Comment: Umm... Uhhhh... Very interesting guess... But it isn't exactly the right answer

Keep guessing tho

Comment: @BenDover Do you imply that this is not completely off-track?

Answer (score 3):

They

> get out the same way they got in.  By communicating with the Enterprise... 4 to beam up!

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> The 4 men are Time Travelers

Explanation

> First, the men build the large room with extra thicc walls, finishing it up from the outside. Next, they go back in time to before the room was built. They stand in the center of where the room will be, and then travel forward in time to when the room is built. They have just entered the room with no door, windows, entrances, or exists. To leave, they simply go back in time to before the room was built.

Comment: Nice answer!







But it isn't correct. Sorry ;-;

Answer (score 1):

> They are four cavers. They walked in and the cave collapsed, sealing them in. The will get out by dying or being rescued.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they

> Were born in there?

And they could

> Break something in half, then put the halves together to make a whole, then jump through the hole to escape?

Comment: I like your answer, but it isn't quite the actual answer. They **entered** the room, which means they couldn't have been born in there.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard one like this before and the answer was...

> Imagination
>  One person or a few people were imagining the situation, in a virtual world or in their head(s). To get out, they just need to stop imagining.

Comment: nice but usually riddles like that begin with "imagine that" or "so-and-so is dreaming"..